# Laravel 5.1 Reset Password Function; user's email is in a different table

Tags: email, laravel, passwords, reset

I have a question regarding Laravel's Reset Password function. I have thoroughly searched for a possible solution and could not find one. Moreover, I tried to scrutinize the code and manually implement it, but failed miserably because of the nesting. (I'm new to Laravel).

According to Laravel's documentation, the user's email must be in the table user in order to work and the error code confirms it.

> *Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'email' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `user` where `email` = usermail@provider.com limit 1*

However, we do have the scenario that an user might have multiple email addresses, hence stored in a different table called user_email.

Does anybody have experience with this scenario and could take the time to enlighten me on this?

Comment: Please,provide the code which causes your error.

Comment: There's no specific code that causes this error since it is the standard implementation, but a different table is needed. A contact gave me the hint it is probably "Vendor->Laravel->Framework->Src->Illuminate->Auth->Passwords->DataBaseTokenRepository.php" I am looking for. I will make required change tomorrow and confirm it. If this solves the problem, I will write an answer to the post how to implement the custom table.

Comment: Even if the user has multiple emails, you should ideally send password reset to one main email. Just a suggestion. And use that email in the users table.

Answer (score 1):

You have two Options:

1. Write your own password recovery system.
2. Let the user choose a primary e-mail and make a column on the users table which represents the primary e-mail adresse.